# `.split()` how to save space more than one?

Tags: python

For example, I have a **file** like this:

```
while True:
    if test = 10:
        print(a, b)
```

Now I wrote a script to read that file, and...print all words in random color. Here is my code:

```
color = [color for color in range(91, 97)]
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        for w in i.split():
            print('\033[{0}m{1}\033[{0};m'
                  .format(random.choice(color), w), end='')
            print(' ', end='')
        print()
```

sure, it's working. but `.split()` didn't save all of the spaces, so the output haven't indent:

```
while True 
if test = 10: 
print(a, b)
```

Now my problem is: How to save the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split based on `' '` (space , instead of `None` which splits by all whitespaces) , and only print the words if it contains anything other than whitespaces (to do this you can simply check if `w.strip()` is empty string or not` . Example -

```
import random
import sys
color = [color for color in range(91, 97)]
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        for w in i.rstrip().split(' '):
            if w.strip():
                print('\033[{0}m{1}\033[{0};m'
                      .format(random.choice(color), w), end='')
            print(' ', end='')
        print()
```

---

Demo -

With OP's code -

```
←[91mwhile←[91;m ←[92mTrue:←[92;m
←[96mif←[96;m ←[92mtest←[92;m ←[95m=←[95;m ←[95m10:←[95;m
←[92mprint(a,←[92;m ←[93mb)←[93;m
```

With above suggested changes -

```
←[93mwhile←[93;m ←[93mTrue:←[93;m
    ←[94mif←[94;m ←[93mtest←[93;m ←[91m=←[91;m ←[94m10:←[94;m
        ←[91mprint(a,←[91;m ←[96mb)←[96;m
```